# Django getting data in my template from nested dictionary(session)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

how do I get the other itens from my session in django and im passing the session as a dictionary in my cart_page.html

my session:

```
{'3': {'quantity': 1, 'price': 4.0, 'totalitem': '4.00'}, '1': {'quantity': 1, 'price': 30.0, 'totalitem': '30.00'}}
```

view.py:

```
   return render(request, 'cart/cart_page.html', {'itens': itens})
```

but when I do:

```
{% for item in itens %}

{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

in my **{{item}}** it only has **3** and **1**, how to I get the quantity and price inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop is used here, at each iteration, the desired value is taken from the nested dictionary from value and checked for presence using:

```
{% if value.quantity or value.price %}
```

templates(cart_page.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>

{% for key, value in itens.items %}
    {% if value.quantity or value.price %}
    {{ 'key ='}} {{ key }}<br>
    {{ 'quantity ='}} {{ value.quantity }}<br>
    {{ 'price ='}} {{ value.price }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('city/', city),
]
```

views.py

```
def city(request):
    itens = {'3': {'quantity': 1, 'price': 4.0, 'totalitem': '4.00'}, '1': {'quantity': 1, 'price': 30.0, 'totalitem': '30.00'}}
    return render(request, "cart/cart_page.html", {"itens": itens})
```

Output

```
key = 3
quantity = 1
price = 4.0
key = 1
quantity = 1
price = 30.0
```

alternatively, you can read the values from the nested dictionary without a loop, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
{{'3 key'}} {{'quantity ='}} {{itens.3.quantity}}   {{'price ='}} {{itens.3.price}}<br>
{{'1 key'}} {{'quantity ='}} {{itens.1.quantity}}   {{'price ='}} {{itens.1.price}}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just one dought "itens.items" I didnt get it

Comment: updated the template code, the keys of the first dictionary are additionally displayed. You are passing an **itens** dictionary to the template. In the template, the loop gets the key and value of the first dimension of the dictionary, that is, 3 and 1 are the keys. Further, through value we get access to nested dictionaries (that is, value is a nested dictionary). And through the dot we get access to the values, for example: value.quantity.  [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) you can see the documentation (section for).

Comment: Added option without loop.